# iOS, CLLocationManager: Displaying the "reenable Location Services" Popup

Tags: iphone, ios, location, core-location

if location services are turned off (after the user once did allow the service) and you then start location updates, a system popup should appear. (the documentation says so in the description of [CLLocationmanager locationServicesEnabled])

But if I setup a test project, which just initialises a CLLocationManager and then calls startLocationUpdates, the popup does NOT appear on every app start. But it should if I understand the documentation right?

I am not talking about the first popup, which asks the user to allow or deny location use for that app. I am talking about the popup, which asks the user to reenable the location services in the settings. That popup has a direct button to the settings application. You can see it, if you disable location services and than open up the maps app. Everytime you press the locate-me button now, the popup appears. Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot Maps App Popup]

I want it to show up reliably on every app start in case the services are disabled. (other apps do it the same way, e.g. aroundme)

Thanks, Markus

Comment: In all my tests, this popup only appears ONCE per app lifetime. So, if it was presented to the user ONCE, it wont appear any time again. Is this right? Can anyone proof this? A client asked to display it at every app start, like the maps app does (when pressing the arrow icon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Popup will only appear once (in some cases twice) for the lifetime of an app!
That is the result of my tests. If anyone has additional information, feel free to write / contact me!
Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: well as I said. you cannot change the behaviour. it will appear only  once per app. thats it..